# How to connect SIP server in react native and make call through WebRTC

Tags: react-native

I'm making a voip calling application using sip server. In the web version, I used the jssip library to connect to the SIP server and make calls successfully, but when switching to the mobile version with react-native I get the error WebRTC not supported. Does anyone know how to fix this error? It would be better if you included the instruction code. I would like to sincerely thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering, "WebRTC not supported," typically arises because React Native environments do not have native WebRTC support like web browsers do. This means that libraries like JsSIP, which rely on WebRTC to function, cannot directly use the browser's WebRTC API in a React Native application.

To overcome this limitation, you can integrate WebRTC into your React Native app by using a WebRTC library designed for React Native. One of the most popular libraries for this purpose is react-native-webrtc.

Here's a step-by-step guide to help you integrate WebRTC into your React Native app for SIP calling:

**Step 1: Install react-native-webrtc**
First, you need to add the react-native-webrtc library to your React Native project:

npm install react-native-webrtc --save

**Step 2: Link Native Code (If Necessary)**
If you are using a React Native version below 0.60, you might need to link the native code manually. For React Native 0.60 and above, autolinking should take care of this.

**Step 3: Modify JsSIP to Use react-native-webrtc**
Since JsSIP is designed to use the browser's WebRTC API, you need to modify it to use the WebRTC API provided by react-native-webrtc. You can do this by configuring the JsSIP instance to use the WebRTC objects from react-native-webrtc.

example

```
import JsSIP from 'jssip';
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  mediaDevices,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

// Override the global WebRTC objects
global.RTCPeerConnection = RTCPeerConnection;
global.RTCIceCandidate = RTCIceCandidate;
global.RTCSessionDescription = RTCSessionDescription;
global.navigator.mediaDevices = mediaDevices;

// Now, you can initialize JsSIP as usual
const socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://your-sip-server.com/ws');
const configuration = {
  sockets: [socket],
  uri: 'sip:your_username@your-sip-server.com',
  password: 'your_password',
};

const ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);

ua.start();
```

**Step 4: Handle Permissions**
Don't forget to request permissions for microphone access, as React Native doesn't automatically request these permissions. You can use libraries like react-native-permissions to manage these requests: